# Removing "\"" from json string

Tags: javascript, json

Hello trying to remove the following example from a jsonString

```
"work_desc":"hello\"world"
```

Tried the following;

```
jsonString = jsonString.replace(new RegExp('\\\"', 'g'), ' ');
```

Would like transform from this:

```
[{"pigsback":0,"work_desc":"hello\"world","owner":"jbb"}]
```

to:

```
[{"pigsback":0,"work_desc":"hello world","owner":"jbb"}]
```

Currently with the above replace code it does this:

```
[{  pigsback :0 work_desc : hello  world , owner :  }]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is **exactly** your JSON string ? How do you get it ?

Comment: Why do you want to "remove" that? `"hello\"world"` is the correct JSON serialisation of the string 'hello"world'. What result do you expect here?

Comment: Because I have a parser that doesn't handle it correctly so I just want to remove all instances of \" fully.

Comment: @DonnchadhO'Leary you better use a proper parser in that case. The browser has not one but two built in. `JSON.parse` is the correct one to use.

Comment: I'm not using it in the browser, I just need to remove \" before I send it to my backend.

Comment: Uh... what environment are you using it in? Node.js has both of these options as well. Worst case scenario you can look at how jQuery does it and use that.

Comment: Could you unhold the question now? Have edited is it more clear? I'm just sending the above by ajax to a backend, just need to make sure (/") is removed first.

Comment: I don't want the backslash or quote to be there, so how could it incorrect parse [{"pigsback":0,"work_desc":"hello world","owner":"jbb"}] ? That's valid?

Comment: Remove any `"` characters *before* you JSON-encode it...?

Answer (score 1):

You could turn your **JSON** into an **object** which will handle all of this for you..

```
JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: What object are you speaking about ?

Comment: The above line of codes takes a **JSON** structure as an argument and returns an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) of that JSON structure

Comment: Except OP didn't show any JSON that would be parsed as an object.

Comment: @dystroy what OP showed looks like an excerpt from an object JSON, or at least something that can be turned into JSON easily

Comment: @JanDvorak We don't even know what OP has to start with, and he's not trying to build an object in the browser (see comments).